# MySQL SELECT only comments that belong to posts viewed on a specific page(pagination using LIMIT)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

Ok so after trying to solive that issue with 10 juniors I am not quite sure how to solve it.

I have 1 MySQL query to pull all 10 *latest* posts from the DB and present them on page 0 of the blog page, from posts table. I am using LIMIT with offset so that PHP can show only 10 posts per page.
That works great:

```
$sql = "
SELECT u.name
     , u.avatar
     , p.id
     , p.user_id
     , p.title
     , p.article
     , DATE_FORMAT(p.set_in,'%d/%m/%Y') date
     , DATE_FORMAT(p.last_edited,'%d/%m/%Y->%H:%i') edited
     , p.genre
     , p.band_image
     , p.albums 
  FROM posts p 
  JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = p.user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY p.set_in DESC
 LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
";
```

Now I want MySQL to select only the comments who belong to the posts which I present, instead of pulling all the comments and matching them using PHP against the relevant ID of the post, but I can't seem to crack it down for some reason.
Based on the fact posts can be deleted I can't use some static logic of ID ranges.

Right now this is my query but it is a really bad one and will not hold for bigger websites:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT u.name,u.avatar,p.id,p.user_id,DATE_FORMAT(c.post_date,'%d/%m/%Y->%H:%i') date, c.ctitle, c.comment, c.id, c.user_id, c.post_id cid FROM comments c "
            . " JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id "
            . " JOIN posts p ON c.post_id = p.id "
            . " ORDER BY c.post_date DESC";
```

This is the comments table:

```
id  post_id user_id ctitle  comment post_date   
1   40  1   hinew   hinew   2017-08-08 00:41:10 
3   40  1   Another Comment test comment    2017-08-08 00:49:15 
4   45  20  How are you fine    2017-08-08 01:06:30 
5   1   1   aftersomefix    yeahhhh 2017-08-08 01:14:12 
6   1   26  dsfgdfg dfgdfg  2017-08-08 01:14:58 
7   45  1   TEST    TEST    2017-08-08 20:42:38
```

This is the posts table:

```
id  user_id title   article set_in      last_edited genre   band_image  albums  
1   1   Demo Text   This is the first post demo text    2017-08-05 18:40:55 2017-08-07 21:17:04 yoyo    2017.08.07.20.17.04-02aacec988bf439c277e2a2b611a23...   popo    
18  19  This is a test  test    2017-08-06 18:43:57 2017-08-07 21:18:11 another test    2017.08.07.20.18.11-177120fbd1a8951e2a70907f5600e5...   wow this is a test  
19  20  This is a 3ed   TEST    2017-08-06 18:49:10 2017-08-07 21:19:14 So many test moses  2017.08.07.20.19.14-17362774_10154643389487979_824...   yes i know we have many tests   
38  1   rtyrtyrty   asdasd  2017-08-07 15:19:57 2017-08-07 21:14:56 Metalcore   2017.08.07.20.14.56-17098309_963035173797767_82275...   aert
jhkghjk
aertaert    
39  1   Dude    Yes I think it does!    2017-08-07 19:54:21 2017-08-07 21:11:47 Is this actually working?   2017.08.07.19.00.53-81c0e26d68e0d29ceb619758e164da...   hi  
40  1   Test albums This is a decp  2017-08-07 20:16:26 2017-08-07 21:11:23 albums genre    2017.08.07.20.01.50-tenor.gif   one,two,tree,four,five,789789,lol   
41  1   BAND EX 1   DESC EX 1   2017-08-08 00:27:45 0000-00-00 00:00:00 GENRE EX 1  2017.08.07.23.27.45-19399240_10158895409495261_149...   EX 1    
42  1   Band ex2    Desc ex 2   2017-08-08 00:28:19 0000-00-00 00:00:00 Genre ex2   2017.08.07.23.28.19-13240136_1004564029622092_8185...   ex 2    
43  1   Name 3  Desc 3  2017-08-08 00:28:52 0000-00-00 00:00:00 Genre 3 2017.08.07.23.28.52-reptilian-death-the-dawn-of-co...   3   
44  1   Name 4  4   2017-08-08 00:29:15 0000-00-00 00:00:00 4   2017.08.07.23.29.15-Best Melodic Death Metal Cover...   4   
45  1   WHAT    hehe    2017-08-08 00:31:52 0000-00-00 00:00:00 MURDER  2017.08.07.23.31.52-Best Melodic Death Metal Cover...   cool
```

I have tried to make a WHERE IN which did not work for me, and as SQL noobie I could not find any relevant solution that includes the pagination factor into it.

Comment: Use your first query as a subquery and join it with the comments table.

Comment: Since you show it on one page I would just load the posts and comments in two seperate queries, you should have a loop that goes through all the posst anyway so you can create a comment query for every post with the post id.

Comment: I already have a loop but I was more interested as to how pull that exact data from MySQL so if I have 10000 comments this won't take forever.
I will try the solution of @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything except of `p.id` from your first query and use it as a subquery. Then join it with the comments table:

```sql
SELECT c.*, u.* -- select the columns you need
FROM comments c
JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT p.id -- other columns if needed in the outer query
    FROM posts p 
    ORDER BY p.set_in DESC
    LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
) p ON p.id = c.post_id
```

Comment: So I have really tried to run this query but something does not seem to work about the posts in field list.
I have tried taking off the alias but it still does not recognize posts.user_id and sometiems posts.id for some reason, this is my query:

SELECT u.name,u.avatar,p.id,p.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(c.post_date,'%d/%m/%Y->%H:%i') cdate, c.ctitle, c.comment, c.id, c.user_id, c.post_id cid FROM comments c 
JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id 
JOIN ( 
SELECT posts.id 
FROM posts 
ORDER BY posts.set_in DESC
LIMIT 1, 10) posts ON posts.id = c.post_id

Comment: Sorry, this is the query, the one above was off.
SELECT u.name
     , u.avatar
     , p.id
     , p.user_id
     , p.title
     , p.article
     , DATE_FORMAT(p.set_in,'%d/%m/%Y') date
     , DATE_FORMAT(p.last_edited,'%d/%m/%Y->%H:%i') edited
     , p.genre
     , p.band_image
     , p.albums
     ,c.ctitle, c.comment, c.id, c.user_id, c.post_id cid
     ,DATE_FORMAT(c.post_date,'%d/%m/%Y->%H:%i') cdate
FROM comments c
JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM posts p 
    ORDER BY p.set_in DESC
    LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit
) p ON p.id = c.post_id

Comment: @YardenSade All comlumns you need from the `posts` table you will need to select in the subquery aswell. Replace `SELECT p.id` with `SELECT p.*`. If that works, then replace `p.*` with the columns you need.